# Strange VBScript error: Object required: 'objFolder'

Tags: vbscript

I have done extensive search on internet but still was not able to find the solution. The interesting thing is that my code worked before. I am using html page with VBScript code, opened using IE 9.

My code is below:

```
29: Function TraverseDirectory(objFolder, searchTerm, outFile)
30: if objFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 then <-- ERROR shown in this line: Object required: 'objFolder' 
31:     MsgBox objFolder.SubFolders.Count <-- This message is shown without an issue
32:     Set fc = objFolder.SubFolders
33:         For Each f1 in fc
34:         ProcessFolder f1, searchTerm, outFile
35:             TraverseDirectory f1, searchTerm, outFile
36:         Next
37: else
38:     ProcessFolder objFolder, searchTerm, outFile
39: end if
40: End Function
```

I am showing the error in line 30: Object required 'objFolder'

I added a message box in line 31 and it was reached, outputting message box with a number of subfolders in a give folder. If the problem was actually in line 30, it would never reach line 31. If I completely remove line 31 (the one with a message box), I still get the same error in line 30.

My function above is called the following way:

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test")
TraverseDirectory objFolder, str, outFile
```

The folder exists and is retrieved without a problem. Not sure what is happening. Can someone shed some light on the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, but it *might* be a scoping issue with the `objFolder` variable. Can you test this by changing `objFolder` to something unique in the function, like `objFolderInsideFunction`?

Comment: What output from `MSGBOX VarType( objFolder) & vbTab & TypeName(objFolder)` between lines 29 and 30 and before the first `TraverseDirectory`?

Comment: the output is "8 Folder" followed by "9  Nothing"

Comment: I figured it out! your comment helped me diagnose it. Can you post it as an answer so i could accept it?

Comment: Actually there is one more issue  when I am looping through subfolders - `Set fc = objFolder.SubFolders  For each f1 in fc` the output come out as "8   String" instead of "8  Folder"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next script collects/echoes some debugging info as advised in [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38056552/strange-vbscript-error-object-required-objfolder#comment63564807_38056552)

```
option explicit
'On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim objfso, str, outfile,  objFolder
set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\TestC")
'Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\attachments") 'an empty folder for debugging'
Wscript.Echo "start" & vbTab _
    & VarType( objFolder) & " " & TypeName(objFolder) & vbTab & objFolder
TraverseDirectory objFolder, str, outFile
Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit

Function TraverseDirectory(objFolder, searchTerm, outFile)
  Dim fc, f1, aux
  Wscript.Echo "debug" & vbTab _
      & VarType( objFolder) & " " & TypeName(objFolder) & vbTab & objFolder
  aux = objFolder.SubFolders.Count
  if aux > 0 then  '<-- ERROR shown in this line: Object required: 'objFolder' 
      'MsgBox objFolder.SubFolders.Count  ' <-- This message is shown without an issue
      Set fc = objFolder.SubFolders
          For Each f1 in fc
              strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & Cstr( aux) _
                  & vbTab & VarType( f1) & " " & TypeName(f1) & vbTab & f1
              'ProcessFolder f1, searchTerm, outFile
              TraverseDirectory f1, searchTerm, outFile
          Next
  else
      'ProcessFolder objFolder, searchTerm, outFile
      strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & Cstr( aux) & vbTab _
          & VarType( objFolder) & " " & TypeName(objFolder) & vbTab & objFolder
  end if
End Function
```

**Debugging scenario**:

```
==> tree "D:\TestC"
Folder PATH listing for volume DataDisk
Volume serial number is … … …
D:\TESTC
├───bubu
│   └───foobar
├───kuku
├───New Folder 12
└───New Folder 21
    └───New folder XX
```

**Output** shows that leafs in folder tree are processed twice so the script above requires more thinking and debugging: note that `strResult` variable is updated in place of *original* `ProcessFolder` call:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\38056552.vbs
start   8 Folder        D:\testC
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC\bubu
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC\bubu\foobar
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC\kuku
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 12
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 21
debug   8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 21\New folder XX
38056552.vbs
4       8 Folder        D:\testC\bubu
1       8 Folder        D:\testC\bubu\foobar
0       8 Folder        D:\testC\bubu\foobar
4       8 Folder        D:\testC\kuku
0       8 Folder        D:\testC\kuku
4       8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 12
0       8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 12
4       8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 21
1       8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 21\New folder XX
0       8 Folder        D:\testC\New Folder 21\New folder XX
```